# how to text in EditText alertdialog can enter in EditText Main #Eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to result encrypted in alertdialog (cipertext) can entered in EditText Main?but I have not been able . is there who can help me?

[image]

Comment: you want encrypted result from the EditText ?

Comment: i want to value on cipertext can copy to edittext send with button Enskripsi?

Answer (score 0):

add in xml:

```
    android:inputType="textPassword"
```